# globle variable

Tags: ios4

I have declare a variable ( int index) in delegate file of application. And also created a property for it `@property (nonatomic, readwrite) int myIndex;` . Now I want to use this variable in another class . I tried but i could not assigned any value to this variable it saws '0'. and ya i have import delegate file in another file. I tried to access this variable by creating delegate's object.

Comment: Try accepting more answers, maulik. This is a community website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your property like this:

```
((ApplicationDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).myIndex
```

`ApplicationDelegate` should be changed to the name of your application delegate if it is different.